# Recording multiplexed Audio/Video to a file using JMF

Tags: java, media, video-capture, jmf, multiplexing

I have a project that uses JMF, and records for a short time (a few seconds to a couple of minutes) both the web camera, and audio inputs, and then writes the results to a file.

The problem with my project is that this file is never produced properly, and cannot be played back.

While I've found numerous examples of how to do multiplexed transmission of audio and video over RTP, or conversion of an input file from one format to another , I haven't seen a working example yet that captures audio and video, and writes it to a file.

Does anyone have an example of functioning code to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the reason why I was not able to generate a file from two separate capture devices under JMF, and it relates to ordering of the start commands.  In particular, things like Processors will take a datasource, or merging datasource, assign and synchronize the time base(s) and start/stop the sources for you, so the extra work I was trying to do starting the datasources manually is utterly redundant, and throws a wrench in the works.

This was a lot of painful trial and error, and I would suggest you read every line of code, understand the sequencing, and understand what has been included, and what has been left out and why before trying to implement this yourself.  JMF is quite the bear if you're not careful.

Oh, and remember to catch exceptions.  I had to omit that code due to length restrictions.

Here's my final solution:

```
public void doRecordingDemo() {

        // Get the default media capture device for audio and video
        DataSource[] sources = new DataSource[2];
        sources[0] = Manager.createDataSource(audioDevice.getLocator());
        sources[1] = Manager.createDataSource(videoDevice.getLocator());

        // Merge the audio and video streams
        DataSource source = Manager.createMergingDataSource(sources);

        // Create a processor to convert from raw format to a file format
        // Notice that we are NOT starting the datasources, but letting the
        //  processor take care of this for us.
        Processor processor = Manager.createProcessor(source);

        // Need a configured processor for this next step
        processor.configure();
        waitForState(processor, Processor.Configured);

        // Modify this to suit your needs, but pay attention to what formats can go in what containers
        processor.setContentDescriptor(new FileTypeDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

        // Use the processor to convert the audio and video into reasonable formats and sizes
        // There are probably better ways to do this, but you should NOT make any assumptions
        // about what formats are supported, and instead use a generic method of checking the
        // available formats and sizes.  You have been warned!
        for (TrackControl control : processor.getTrackControls()) {
            if (control.getFormat() instanceof VideoFormat || control.getFormat() instanceof AudioFormat) {
                if (control.getFormat() instanceof AudioFormat) {
                    // In general, this is safe for audio, but do not make assumptions for video.
                    // Things get a little wonky for video because of how complex the options are.
                    control.setFormat(new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.GSM));
                }

                if (control.getFormat() instanceof VideoFormat) {
                    VideoFormat desiredVideoFormat = null;
                    Dimension targetDimension = new Dimension(352, 288);

                    // Search sequentially through this array of formats
                    VideoFormat[] desiredFormats = new VideoFormat[] {new H263Format(), new JPEGFormat(), new RGBFormat(), new YUVFormat()};
                    for (VideoFormat checkFormat : desiredFormats) {
                        // Search the video formats looking for a match.
                        List<VideoFormat> candidates = new LinkedList<VideoFormat>();
                        for (Format format : control.getSupportedFormats()) {
                            if (format.isSameEncoding(checkFormat)) {
                                candidates.add((VideoFormat) format);
                            }
                        }
                        if (!candidates.isEmpty()) {
                            // Get the first candidate for now since we have at least a format match
                            desiredVideoFormat = candidates.get(0);

                            for (VideoFormat format : candidates) {
                                if (targetDimension.equals(format.getSize())) {
                                    // Found exactly what we're looking for
                                    desiredVideoFormat = format;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (desiredVideoFormat != null) {
                            // If we found a match, stop searching formats
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (desiredVideoFormat != null) {
                        // It's entirely possible (but not likely) that we got here without a format
                        //  selected, so this null check is unfortunately necessary.
                        control.setFormat(desiredVideoFormat);
                    }
                }
                control.setEnabled(true);
                System.out.println("Enabled track: " + control + " (" + control.getFormat() + ")");
            }

        }

        // To get the output from a processor, we need it to be realized.
        processor.realize();
        waitForState(processor, Processor.Realized);

        // Get the data output so we can output it to a file.
        DataSource dataOutput = processor.getDataOutput();

        // Create a file to receive the media
        File answerFile = new File("recording.mov");
        MediaLocator dest = new MediaLocator(answerFile.toURI().toURL());

        // Create a data sink to write to the disk
        DataSink answerSink = Manager.createDataSink(dataOutput, dest);

        // Start the processor spinning
        processor.start();

        // Open the file
        answerSink.open();

        // Start writing data
        answerSink.start();

        // SUCCESS!  We are now recording
        Thread.sleep(10000);  // Wait for 10 seconds so we record 10 seconds of video

        try {
            // Stop the processor. This will also stop and close the datasources
            processor.stop();
            processor.close();

            try {
                // Let the buffer run dry.  Event Listeners never seem to get called,
                // so this seems to be the most effective way.
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            try {
                // Stop recording to the file.
                answerSink.stop();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                // Whatever else we do, close the file if we can to avoid leaking.
                answerSink.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            try {
                // Deallocate the native processor resources.
                processor.deallocate();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
}

// My little utility function to wait for a given state.
private void waitForState(Player player, int state) {
    // Fast abort
    if (player.getState() == state) {
        return;
    }

    long startTime = new Date().getTime();

    long timeout = 10 * 1000;

    final Object waitListener = new Object();

    ControllerListener cl = new ControllerListener() {

        @Override
        public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce) {
            synchronized (waitListener) {
                waitListener.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        player.addControllerListener(cl);

        // Make sure we wake up every 500ms to check for timeouts and in case we miss a signal
        synchronized (waitListener) {
            while (player.getState() != state && new Date().getTime() - startTime < timeout) {
                try {
                    waitListener.wait(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        // No matter what else happens, we want to remove this
        player.removeControllerListener(cl);
    }
}
```